# Using imagemagick to identify all files in multiple subfolders

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick

I want to run [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php) with the `identify` option to scan all images in multiple folders at one time.

It should be run similar to the below syntax but I want to log it all to the same one log file, and I'd like to make a batch file for this if possible too.

```
magick identify -verbose "D:\Images" >log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: I prefer to use Irfanview thumbnails to see all the subfolders  OR (voidtools.com Everything ... to list all the files ( by type e.g. images, docs, or *.png )  OR Treesize View explorer extension to see a pareto chart of file sizes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just run a [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) loop with a [DIR](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) command to get the full explicit path to each file from the source directory (D:\Images) and traverse it recursively.

This essentially passes each full explicit path and file name to the `magick` command one-by-one and then you will append these to the log file for later review.

Additional resources and an example command with applicable syntax using all this is provided for you below to utilize accordingly. This should be a good starting point for you.

---

### Command Line Example

<sub>**NOTE:**</sub> <sub>You can replace the portion of
`D\Images\*.*"` as `D\Images\*.jpg"` or whatever file extensions to
only list those particular file extensions and you could also change
it to `F:\OtherFolder\*.png"` or whatever for the need so a different
folder path and/or file extensions can be specified in that portion of
the example I provided below.</sub>

```
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %A IN ('DIR /A-D /S /B "D:\Images\*.*"') DO magick identify -verbose "%~A">>D:\logfile.txt
```

---

### Batch Script Example

<sub>**NOTE:**</sub> <sub>I made this script so you can set the variables for your needs up top easily to accommodate accordingly per run.</sub>

```
@ECHO ON

SET Source=D:\Images
SET Ext=*.jpg
SET LogFile=D:\logfile.txt

FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%A IN ('DIR /A-D /S /B "%Source%\%Ext%"') DO magick identify -verbose "%%~A">>"%LogFile%"
GOTO EOF
```

---

### Further Resources

- [**FOR /F**](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [**DIR**](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [**Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes**](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)
- [**Redirection**](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Answer (score 0):

The following one liner (works on Linux, but probably also on Windows 10 using the Windows PowerShell) gives you a recursive list of all jpg images in the underlying directories and their details:

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -exec identify {} \;
```